# Can you write a formula to Excel from C# when writing to a range of cells?

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have a home-built utility to transfer data from a DataSet to an Excel spreadsheet. I want to put a formula (e.g. "=+RC[-2]-RC[-1]") in one of the columns. However, Excel is treating it a string and not interpreting it as a formula. The utility creates and transfers an array of objects to a Range in Excel. Is this the problem? I have written formulas to Excel in the past, but only when writing to a single cell.

```
for (int r = 0; r < nr; r++)
   {
      r = dt.Rows[r];
      nOut++;

      aRng = new object[nc];
      for (int c = 0; c < nc; c++) else aRng[c] = dr[c];

      oRng = oSheet.get_Range(CellAddress(nOut, 1), CellAddress(nOut, nc));
      oRng.Value2 = aRng;
   }
```

Comment: Never met addressing like `RC[-2]` in Excel.

Comment: @kirilloid: http://www.lytebyte.com/2008/04/29/what-are-a1-and-r1c1-reference-style-in-excel/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the .Formula property in order to force excel to treat it as a formula.

```
((Range)worksheet.Cells[row, col]).Formula = myFormula
```

Comment: Based on my experiments, entering the formula as a string into Value will work. I had done this in the past. My problem here was that the NumberFormat of the column had been set to "@". When I set it to a numeric format ("#,##0.00"), it recognized the formula. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out. Best of luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `.Formula` or `FormulaR1C1` property of the `Range` object.

```
string s = "=+RC[-2]-RC[-1]";
...
oRng.FormulaR1C1 = s;
```